# Getting data from Marketscreener via Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the list of all holdings in an ETF into .csv file

[text](https://de.marketscreener.com/kurs/etf/DEKA-EURO-ISTOXX-EX-FIN-D-40509374/einzelwerte/)

I tried it via a beautifulSoup, but it delivers no data. I tried also a code from the forum, same result. Did they changed the site to js outputs?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Define the URL which I want to scrape
url = 'https://de.marketscreener.com/kurs/etf/DEKA-EURO-ISTOXX-EX-FIN-D-40509374/einzelwerte/'

# Define user-agent header to mimic a web browser
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
}

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL with headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    all_data = {}
    # for every table found on page...
    for table in soup.select('table.BordCollapseYear2'):
        table_name = table.find_previous('b').text
        all_data[table_name] = []
        # ..scrape every row
        for tr in table.select('tr'):
            row = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
            if len(row) == 7:
                all_data[table_name].append(row)

    # pretty print all data:
    for k, v in all_data.items():
        print('Table name: {}'.format(k))
        print('-' * 160)
        for row in v:
            print(('{:<25}' * 7).format(*row))
        print()




else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for k, v in all_data.items():
        spamwriter.writerow([k])
        for row in v:
            spamwriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous methods for obtaining a list of all holdings in an ETF in a.csv file.

**You can try that approach based on your code.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

# Define the URL you want to scrape
url = 'https://de.marketscreener.com/kurs/etf/DEKA-EURO-ISTOXX-EX-FIN-D-40509374/einzelwerte/'

# Define user-agent header to mimic a web browser
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"
}

# Send an HTTP GET request to the URL with headers
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

    all_data = {}
    # for every table found on page...
    for table in soup.select('table.BordCollapseYear2'):
        table_name = table.find_previous('b').text
        all_data[table_name] = []
        # ..scrape every row
        for tr in table.select('tr'):
            row = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
            if len(row) == 7:
                all_data[table_name].append(row)

    # pretty print all data:
    for k, v in all_data.items():
        print('Table name: {}'.format(k))
        print('-' * 160)
        for row in v:
            print(('{:<25}' * 7).format(*row))
        print()

    # Write the data to a CSV file
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        for k, v in all_data.items():
            spamwriter.writerow([k])
            for row in v:
                spamwriter.writerow(row)

else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")
```